# Multiple input fields and buttons on single line using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-bootstrap

I have the following single line containing an search input bar and 2 buttons. How do I style this to make the search input box smaller according to the buttons next to it? I would like to add 2 more input fields to the right of the search box and to the left of the buttons shown in the image. Is there a way to do this without  using "col-md-x"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrWBi.png

This is what I have so far but I feel like it is very hacky.

```
<div class="col-md-10 search-left">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn" dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle first-dropdown" dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-btn" dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle second-dropdown"
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search term" ng-model="search.value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 search-right">
    <div class="pull-right" popover="Please select rows to export" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
        <button class='btn btn-default'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button class='btn btn-default add-item' ng-click="addItem()">Add Staff</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.form-inline` to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for left-aligned and inline-block controls.